# Precalculate ASP.NET Embedded WebRessource Url

Tags: asp.net, url, webresource.axd

I have the following Problem.
In an `Assembly`, there are Resources which are exported via "WebRessource" Attribute

Ok. I know that the through the Method `GetWebRessourceUrl`, I can find out the Ressource Url but this happens basically at Runtime.

I need this Resource Url at Compiletime.

Why?

Because I have a Javascript which calls some of the the WebRessource Urls.
The Tricky Part is, this Javascript is also in a assembly embedded (The same Assembly as the other Resources) and is Generated and embedded at compile Time with the other Ressources.

I am grateful for every help.

Comment: could you clarify, when you say your javascript "calls some of the WebResource Urls" what do you mean?  You are calling functions within those files or you actually need to request the file as a URL?

Comment: i manipulate a dom element. I want to set the "src" attribute to the webresource url. And all this at Build time.